# How to make my class iterable by BOOST_FOREACH in C++?

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, boost-foreach

**EDIT**: I give up! I am using simply `for (string& word : sentence) { .. }` instead now. `BOOST_FOREACH` is hopeless. Thank you.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597695/make-my-c-class-iterable-via-boost-foreach), and [this](http://boost-sandbox.sourceforge.net/libs/foreach/doc/html/boost_foreach/extending_boost_foreach.html), and they did not help at all. Especially I want to ask about the second link. Why do you have to define some strange structs under the namespace `boost`? The class that I want to enable BOOST_FOREACH for is defined in my own namespace. How can I access data from that class if I define my iterators in `namespace boost { .. }`? This makes no sense. I don't know why finding the equivalence of `IEnumerable` in C++ took me so much time! Wans't `boost` supposed to save my time?

Could anybody just tell me the neatest way to iterate over this class:

```
class Sentence {
private:
    vector<string> words;
}
```

with this code:

```
Sentence sentence;
BOOST_FOREACH(string word, sentence) {
    // ..
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This snippet from an answer *you* linked to pretty much sums it up: Once you have defined an iterator class, you just have to add begin() and end() member functions to your class.

Comment: My `Sentence` class is defined in a namespace of my own. How can I access the `words` (which is not only in another namespace, but also a private member) from those iterators defined in the namespace `boost`?

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/foreach.html), anything that looks like a standard library container would work. The simplest way would be to expose a pair of iterators in your class. If you do not want to implement your own, simply use `vector<string>` iterators:

```
class Sentence 
{
public:
  typedef vector<string>::iterator iterator;
  typedef vector<string>::const_iterator const_iterator;
  const_iterator begin() const { return words.begin(); }
  const_iterator end() const { return words.end(); }
private:
    vector<string> words;
};
```

**Edit** it seems `BOOST_FOREACH` is not clever enough to understand standard library container-like types, but it can understand a pair of standard library iterators. So an extra step is required:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
int main()
{
  Sentence sentence;
  auto s = std::make_pair(sentence.begin(), sentence.end());
  BOOST_FOREACH(std::string word, s) {
    std::cout << word << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Note 1: You may want to de-couple the explicit type of the iterator using *type erasure*, but that could be seen as a refinement. See [this relevant discussion](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html) for more information.

Note 2: I was never a big fan of `BOOST_FOREACH`. C++11 range based loops make it even less likely that I would use it in real code.

Comment: I have tried this. But this only supports C++ 11 foreach syntax (`for (string word in sentence`). It does not support BOOST_FOREACH.

Comment: @SMTNinja You are right, it isn't as clever as I assumed. It works with a pair of iterators, but I would still prefer a range based loop.